# How to handle friend request accept logic in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a simple social app and have a `user_friend` table which has both the `user_id` and `friend_id` as its composite keys. In the front end, the current user can look at other people's profiles and then click on add friend button which updates the `user_friend` table. For example, user with id 100 can view user with id 9's and 15's profiles and click on add button and then the `user_friend` table gets updated as

```
user_id: 100, friend_id 9
```

and

```
user_id: 100, friend_id 15
```

What is the best approach to handling such request? I was thinking creating a new table called `request_table` which has `requester` column which has the id for the user, `accepter` column which has the id for the friend and `status` column with accepted and pending. So, when requester clicks add friend button, the status gets updated to accepted which then updates the `user_friend` table to to reflect the change (by adding a new row user_id: 9, friend_id 100 in the above example).
Please advice if there are cleaner or better ways to do this.

Comment: Or you can put a status column in the user-friend table and have statuses like `pending` or `accepted` or `rejected`

Comment: You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make it much simpler than you are thinking ..  Your current table looks like:

```
+--------------------------------+
|   user_id    |    friend_id    |
+--------------+-=---------------+
|     100      |       15        |
+--------------+-----------------+
|     100      |        9        |
+--------------+-----------------+
```

Add two columns .. `requested` and `accepted`:

```
+--------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+
|   user_id    |    friend_id    |    requested    |    accepted    |
+--------------+-=---------------+-----------------+----------------+
|     100      |       15        |        1        |         0      |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|     100      |        9        |        1        |         1      |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Although one could ASSUME that if the entry is in the table `requested` will always be `1` -- So really you only need to add the `accepted` column ..  But you get the basic idea/principle.

**NOTE** if you need more statuses than just "accepted" like -- Say  "blocked" or "suspended" etc etc you can create a third table and use the in a relational way.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|              user_firends (uf_id for indexing FASTER)           |
+--------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+
|      uf_id   |     user_id     |    friend_id    |    status    |
+--------------+-=---------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       1      |      100        |        9        |       1      |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       2      |      100        |        15       |       2      |
+--------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+

+---------------------------------------+
|             statuses_table            |
+------------------+--------------------+
|      status_id   |        status      |
+------------------+--------------------+
|         1        |      requested     | 
+------------------+--------------------+
|         2        |       accepted     |
+------------------+--------------------+
|         3        |       rejected     |
+------------------+--------------------+
|         4        |       blocked      |
+------------------+--------------------+
```

1. many (users) to many (friends) with a `users_friends` "pivot" table AND
2. many (friends) to single (staus) with a direct insert of status in the column

Comment: Great. Thank yiu for your answer.